# Will my iPhone receive messages after i re-activate it?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4s was deactivated last night by my father because I am grounded. I'm not going to have it for ten days and right now it is powered off and lying on the dining room table and, like I said, deactivated. When I turn it back on and he reactivates it, will I receive the texts sent to me during that time period of deactivation? I have Verizon, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Deactivated by Verizon? if yes no you will not get them. Or did you Dad rightfully so just take out the battery ?

Comment: Or did hi actually go to Verizon store to deactivate it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the good and bad news.

> [If I have my device turned off, will I still receive text messages?](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/faqs/TXTmessaging/faq.html)
>
> If a message is sent to you while your device is off, or while you're
>   traveling outside of the Verizon Wireless coverage area, your message
>   will be stored for later delivery. Your device must be turned back on
>   and have coverage for the message to be delivered to you. The network
>   will attempt to deliver the message for **five days (120 hours)** from the
>   date of receipt. Messages not delivered within five days will be
>   deleted.

If it is officially Deactivated at Verizon store (or web site) then you will get nothing